# Spring Security: oauth2Login redirect only on certain paths

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have Spring Security configured to authenticate my website, such that all paths are automatically redirected to the OAuth2 authorization URL (using `.oauth2Login()`). However, I want unauthenticated requests to the API (i.e. `/api/**`) to return `401 Unauthorized` instead of being redirected. I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my current configuration:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/auth/oauth2/callback").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .oauth2Login()
    .authorizationEndpoint()
    .baseUri(this.oauth2AuthorizationRedirectBaseUri);

http.logout()
    .logoutUrl("/auth/logout")
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a custom authentication entry point for /API/** and add t to your configuration:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authEx) 
      throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    setRealmName("developers");
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
}

}
```

in your Http security configs add:

```
 http.
     ...
     .exceptionHandling()
     .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
              new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint(),
              new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"))
```

Comment: This worked great for me, although the `afterPropertiesSet` threw an error about not having a realmName set, so I just commented out the `super.after...` call.

Comment: I removed afterPropertiesSet() completely as it's no required in this case

Comment: Actually, without the `afterPropertiesSet` being overridden and specifically doing nothing, it will re-introduce that error because it will have the same effect as calling `super.afterPropertiesSet()`

Comment: you're right 'BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint ' has an assertion in it's 'afterPropertiesSet' method. I updated the answer and set the realm property